# "Game" in the meaning of "wild animals"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Take a look at this text:

"Dogs that stretch their circles far into the snow-covered winter forest are better kept on a leash on certain sections of the route. In winter, *the game* often stays in valleys near the feeding sites resting. *The game* has little chance to escape. The animals drive down their metabolism in winter and then have to drive it up for flight. This is extremely stressful for them."

I googled it and one of the meanings is "animals that are hunted for fun". This text is about cross-country skiing with your dog etiquette, so no relation to hunting. But, even if I accept "the game" to be wild animals, then why does it say "the game has little chance to escape"? It's the pet dog who would need to escape then. I'm very confused.

Comment: The first paragraph starts "Dogs that stretch their circles far into the ... forest." They don't know that your own dog won't do that, e.g. chase the animals and exhaust them. Those are the dogs that should be kept on a leash, not yours.

Comment: @WeatherVane Is "Dogs that stretch their circles far into the ... forest." referring to when I ski with my dog, and the dog follows me, but not necesserily on the tracks, it can also run through the forest nearby following me? And that could be dangerous? I'm now also confused about "stretch their circles"

Comment: It means the dog might be accustomed to ranging far off on its own. It does not matter whether your dog is chasing the animals, or being chased *by* them. Either will deplete the wintering animals of energy that they can't afford to lose. The dog does not even need to be actively *chasing* them: its presence might be enough to make them want to escape its vicinity.

Answer (score 3):

In the text, ‘the game’ *is* referring to wild animals; it is saying that your dog will chase after them if you’re cross-country skiing in valleys with wild animals, because the dog will want to chase after them. The wild animals (the game) will have little chance to escape *from your dog*.

Hope this helps!